# Way to delete the entire column in excel macro based on column header value that contains some string

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to delete the entire column in excel macro based on column header value that contains some string.

Note: If the column header appears n number of times, it has to find and delete n number of columns in vb macro.

Let's say i have a Column header called "COLUMN_6" which appears two times, then my code has to find the column header that contains COLUMN_6 and it has to delete these two columns.

[image]

I have written the below code and it's working partially.

```
Sub ClearSpecificColumns()

    Dim last_col As Long

    'get the last column
    last_col = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

     MsgBox ("222" & last_col)

    'iterate from 1 to last column
    For i = 1 To last_col

        If Cells(1, i).Value Like "COLUMN_6" Then

           Columns(i).Delete

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

**Problems:**

The above code finds and deletes ONLY ONE TIME (the first appearance only) the entire column with COLUMN_6. It's supposed to delete both the two columns.

why it's NOT iterating for the 2nd time to delete the second appearance of COLUMN_6 in this case.

Any other easy and fast way to do this?

Comment: If you're deleting, loop from the right to left.

Comment: `For i = last_col To 1 Step -1` as per BigBen's comment. Additionally I recommend to reference the sheet for `Cells(1, i).Value` and `Columns(i).Delete`. • Also I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* and declare all your variables properly. eg you forgot `Dim i As Long`.

Comment: Also, if you're working with Sheet1, then you should qualify all the instances of `Cells` and `Columns` - right now there's an implicit `ActiveSheet`, when you really should specify the worksheet.

Comment: Also - if the header contains more than just "COLUMN_6", then add wildcards: `Like "*COLUMN_6*"`

Comment: You could do this using `FIND` and `<range>.EntireColumn`. This way you don't need the loop

Comment: Team, I have to implement the below formula (convert millisec to DATE format) in the middle of my code ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]/86400000)+DATE(1970,1,1)" but how can i check if the RC[-1] value is NON BLANK or NOT EMPTY before i apply this formula? Please suggest!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please raise a new question for your formula issue. You should only have 1 question per post

Answer (score 0):

You could take the duplicates columns into an array, then make a single range with all the columns with the duplicates and erase them at once:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim MyHeaders As Range
Dim ToDelete() As Variant
Dim i As Long

Dim last_col As Long

'get the last column
last_col = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set MyHeaders = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, last_col))

ReDim ToDelete(MyHeaders.Count)

i = 0
For Each rng In MyHeaders
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MyHeaders, rng.Value) > 1 Then
        'it's duplicated. We store the column number
        ToDelete(i) = rng.Column
    Else
        'it's unique, we store a 0
        ToDelete(i) = 0
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next rng

For i = 0 To UBound(ToDelete) Step 1
    If ToDelete(i) <> 0 Then
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = MyHeaders.Cells(1, ToDelete(i)).EntireColumn
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, MyHeaders.Cells(1, ToDelete(i)).EntireColumn)
        End If
    End If
Next i

Erase ToDelete
rng.Delete xlShiftToLeft

Set rng = Nothing
Set MyHeaders = Nothing
```